# Configuration.GetSection always returns Value property null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Every time I call `Configuration.GetSection`, the `Value` property of the returned object is always null.

My `Startup` constructor

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();

    this.Configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

My `ConfigureServices` method

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<SqliteSettings>(opts => Configuration.GetSection("SqliteSettings").Bind(opts));

    services.AddOptions();

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

My `appsettings.json`

```
{
  "SqliteSettings": {
    "DataSource": "C:\\db.sqlite",
    "NewDatabase": true,
    "Version": 3
  }
}
```

The class I'm using to define SqliteSettings

```
public class SqliteSettings
{
    public string DataSource { get; set; }

    public bool? NewDatabase { get; set; }

    public int? Version { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public long? CacheSize { get; set; }

    // More properties
}
```

I was thinking the JSON might need to have the same amount of properties to match, or is it might be something to do with data type definitions, but maybe those are completely unrelated.

Comment: I think the best answer is this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52273140/940223

Answer (score 185, accepted):

According to the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#getsection-getchildren-and-exists):

> When GetSection returns a matching section, Value isn't populated. A
> Key and Path are returned when the section exists.

If you want to see the values of that section you will need to call the GetChildren() method: `Configuration.GetSection("SqliteSettings").GetChildren();`

Or you can use:
`Configuration.GetSection("SqliteSettings").Get<SqliteSettings>()`. The JSON does not need to have the same amount of properties to match. Unmatched nullable properties will be set to null and non-nullable unmatched properties will be set to their default value (e.g. int will be set to 0).

Comment: Configuration.GetSection("SqliteSettings").Bind(sqliteSettingsObject);  is another way to read the settings

Comment: If you just need to see if the section is present, you can use the Exists() method, as in
`Configuration.GetSection("SqliteSettings").Exists()`

Comment: The .Get<>() version worked fine for me. Frustratingly, MSDN just shows an As cast in use, and I bet that's confusing a lot of people.

Comment: I think it's better to use this approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/52273140/940223

Comment: I kept getting an instance of the object, but all of the properties were null. Turns out that I had defined my properties without a setter (ie `public string MyString { get; }`) and that wasn't allowing .NET to map to my object

Comment: To be able to use `.Get<SqliteSettings>()` you need to add `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder` nuget package to your project.

Answer (score 53):

1. Right-click on `appsettings.json` and go to Properties.
2. Select Copy to output directory = Copy always.

Comment: So much time wasted for something so simple..... Thanks.

Comment: Same here! The copyifnever is so confusing. The file will be copied just once and new settings you added will not get through. At the end, it appears some of the settings will go through, some will not!

Comment: This is the exact answer, Thanks You are a life saver

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so much! It's so unintuitive

Comment: I swear, this crap still gets me to this day. Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

Just modify your `ConfigureServices` method to be like following:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddOptions();

    services.Configure<SqliteSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("SqliteSettings"));

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

and it should work.

Comment: Unforunately, did not work, although the order placement probably solves bugs that would occur in the future. `Configuration.GetSection` still returns with `.Value` being null.

Comment: Could you share how you are calling `.Value`?

Comment: To see if I was getting the JSON, was simply doing `var x = Configuration.GetSection("SqliteSettings");` then inspecting x in Visual Studio, specifically for `Value`.

Comment: If you want to read directly from `Configuration`, use something like `Configuration["SqliteSettings:DataSource"];`. And if you want to use it in controllers use **options pattern**

Comment: I understood that in Startup.cs you can only get configuration json's "leaves" unlike in .net core 1 or so, and use such code:


services_.Configure<CorporateConfiguration>(
                options_ =>
                {
                    options_.Name = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Corporate:Name");
                    options_.BrandLogo = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Corporate:BrandLogo");
                });

Comment: @LiamMueller, as far as I understand - Configuration.GetSection("SqliteSettings") has null Value property because this property has string type (see IConfigurationSection interface). SqliteSettings is not a plain JSON string, it is an object. So you can call Configuration.GetSection("SqliteSettings").Get<SqliteSettings>() to get value for that section

Answer (score 12):

If all the other answers do not fix the problem, another reason could be that the properties of the Options class are private (or do not have accessible setters).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Apparently `internal` is not sufficiently accessible for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I defined only the getter for the setting class properties.

Answer (score 8):

My problem was that the .bind() method's object instance was not intialized.

```
services.Configure<SqliteSettings>(opts => Configuration.GetSection("SqliteSettings").Bind(opts));
```

So before calling .bind(opts); I initialized the value:

```
SqlliteSettings opts = new SqliteSettings();
```

Binded the local settings variable:

```
Configuration.GetSection(AppSettingsSectionName).Bind(opts);
```

And did the container registration separately:

```
services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("SqlliteSettings"));
```

This solved the problem since the .Bind() method will just return null when the instance provided is null.

Comment: OMG. You are a hero, MS are dumb. Why wouldn't you initialise if you're setting a value?

Comment: Initialize the binding target! You saved my day sir!

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me in a console application:

```
var connectionString = config["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"]
```

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have property accessors on your configuration object, otherwise it won't bind properly.  Knowing this would have saved me 2 hours today.

```
public class MyConfiguration
{
        public string ConfigurationOption1; // BAD
        public string ConfigurationOption2 { get; set; } // GOOD
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is! And we must remember to configure all as public

Comment: D'oh! This was my issue, had set marked as internal. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
```

must come after all `services.Configure` calls.

Comment: You should never build service provider manually.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was using VS Code and .net core 3.x webapp.

I was facing similar issue that GetSection() or Configuraton["Section:KeyName"] returned null,
I checked GetSection().Exists() which also returned false.

So I tried Adding configbuilder inside ConfigureServices which helped me fix this,

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
      //Initialize the builder 
      var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory)
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT")}.json", optional: true)//To specify environment
                    .AddEnvironmentVariables();//You can add if you need to read environment variables.

      //Build the configuration
      IConfiguration Configuration = builder.Build();

       
      services.Configure<SqliteSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("SqliteSettings"));
      //Similar to below 
      //services.Configure<EntityClass>(Configuration.GetSection("EntityConfigSection"));
      
  }
```

Note: Please make sure the value cwd and program under .VScode/launch.json has the right values.
The code picks the current working directory from the cwd Value so we need to make sure its set correct.

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "X.X.X",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
        "type": "coreclr",
        "request": "launch",
        "preLaunchTask": "build",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/<ProjectLocation>/bin/<BuildType>/<Version>/<ProjectDll>",
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/<ProjectLocation>",
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "serverReadyAction": {
            "action": "openExternally",
            "pattern": "\\bNow listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
        },
        "env": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        },
        "sourceFileMap": {
            "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
        }
    }

]}
```

Comment: The configuration snippet in this answer is useful as it will throw an error if `appsettings.json` could not be found. This helped me to track down my problem, which was that in `launch.json`, the `cwd` value was set to the wrong folder, which is *super* tricky to notice as everything works except the config stuff. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your dependency injection is failing and you have concluded that this method is the problem after debugging it, it's not!

This is enough for registration:

```
services.Configure<SqliteSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("SqliteSettings"));
```

You have to inject your configuration class in [IOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.options.ioptions-1?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) interface. That will solve the DI issue. I have wasted a few hours on the issue, hope it helps someone else.

Comment: How did you did it?

Comment: @EduCielo Injected IOptions<SqliteSettings>

Answer (score 0):

In my case for Web Api Core 2.1, I needed `Program.cs` in the project root folder (the same folder as Startup.cs).

Answer (score 0):

Try add ConfigurationProvider to ConfigurationBuilder.

App configuration is provided from:

- appsettings.json using the File Configuration Provider.
- appsettings.{Environment}.json using the File Configuration Provider.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not accidentally nesting your variables within the default `Logging` object.  I had been sticking all sorts of variables in the wrong level of brackets (but it was accidentally correct in the default appsettings.json), resulting in mysteriously absent keys/values.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add the code in correct appsettings.json file.
There might be multiple appsettings.json files like appsettings.Development.json, appsettings.QA.json depending on the project and thus based on the environment, your code will be executed.

Answer (score -1):

If you have an `appsettings.Development.json` file, make sure the "ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection" settings are the same in both the `appsettings.Development.json` and `appsettings.json` files.

Comment: Thank you: the file `appsettings.Development.json` was present in my source folder but not shown in VS2019.