# Configuration GetSection returns null value for object sections

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Hello i am using a a `json` configuration file within a `.NET Core App` and i do not understand why i get the value null for subsections that are objects:

```js
{
    "tt": {
        "aa":3,
        "x":4
    },
    "Url":333,
    "Config": {
        "Production": {
            "RedisAddress": {
                "Hostname": "redis0",
                "Port": 6379
            },
            "OwnAddress": {
                "Hostname": "0.0.0.0",
                "Port": 9300
            }
        },
        "Dev": {
            "RedisAddress": {
                "Hostname": "redis0",
                "Port": 6379
            },
            "OwnAddress": {
                "Hostname": "0.0.0.0",
                "Port": 9300
            },
            "Logger": "logger.txt"
        }
    }
}
```

When i try `GetSection("Config")` or `GetSection("tt")` i get the value `null`.It however  returns the value for primitive types like in my case `Url`.

What is funny is that if i peek inside the `configuration.Providers[0].Data` i have all the content present like in the picture:

[image]

Why does it return null for `object` types?

**Code**

```
WebHostBuilder builder = new WebHostBuilder();
builder.UseStartup<Startup>();

string appPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
string jsonPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetParent(appPath).FullName).FullName, "appsettings.json");

IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(appPath)
    .AddJsonFile(jsonPath, optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .Build();

var sect = configuration.GetSection("Config");//has value null
var sect2 = configuration.GetSection("tt");//has value null
var sect3 = configuration.GetSection("Url"); has value 333
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Configuration.GetSection always returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46017593/configuration-getsection-always-returns-null)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both answers ([TanvirArjel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53873316/10816950) and [Kirk Larkin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53872359/10816950)) are correct.
I am just going to clarify things for you and provide another way of getting the value form the configuration file.

To get a value from `appsettings.json` you need to pass the path of the value (`colon-separated`) to the `configuration`.

There are different ways to get the value without binding the section to a class. E.g.:

```
var aaAsString = configuration["tt:aa"]; //will return the value as a string "3".
//To get the actual value type you need to cast them 
var aa1 = configuration.GetValue<int>("tt:aa"); //returns 3.
var aa2 = configuration.GetSection("tt").GetValue<int>("aa");
var aa3 = configuration.GetSection("tt").GetValue(typeof(int), "aa");
```

Comment: So i have tried `configuration.GetSection("Config:Production).GetValue<Address>("RedisAddress")` and i still get `null`.I have also tried `configuration.GetSection("Config:Production:RedisAddress).Value"` and again i get `null`.Address is a `struct`.I can't extract objects? Do i need to extract the primitives one by one ?

Comment: You can create a class `ProductionConfig` that has `Address` struct in it, then retrieve the production configuration as `configuration.GetSection("Config:Production").Get<ProductionConfig>();`. This should work. Note: `Address` should have matching names with the keys inside the `Config:Production:Address`

Comment: Now i have a class for `Address` .Do i need to strong -type the enclosing type too , to be able to retrieve the child?In my case i have `RedisAddress` which is of type `Address`.Do i need to strong-type the `Dev`/`Production` section too ?

Comment: Yes, otherwise you would get something like `failed to convert 'THE VALUE' to type 'Type' `. You can have the proprieties that you want to retrieve from the configuration, you don't have to have all the sections.

Comment: So following this principle i have to always strong-type the root right?Having everything in the hierarchy strongly-typed,otherwise i can not acess small pieces of the json.

Comment: I am not sure, but probably yeah you need to respect the `Path` to get the small pieces of the json. Or you can implement `extension methods` to get specific section/value, same idea as `GetConnectionString` provided by `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`.

Answer (score 7):

There is nothing wrong in your example. The `Value` property you're referring to is a `string`, which is `null` for both your `sect` and `sect2` variables simply because neither of these contain a `string` value - they are both objects, as you've stated.

If you want to pull out a value from e.g. `sect2`, you can do so using something like this:

```
var aaValue = sect2.GetValue<int>("aa");
```

There are a few more options for getting the values for a section like this. Here's another example that will bind to a POCO:

```
public class TT
{
    public int AA { get; set; }
    public int X { get; set; }
}

var ttSection = sect2.Get<TT>();
```

If all you want to do is get a nested value, there’s really no reason to use `GetSection` at all. For example, you can just do the following:

```
var redisHostname = configuration["Config:Dev:RedisAddress:Hostname"];
```

Comment: I want to pull the section but not bind it to a `POCO` since i will next need just a fieldfrom it in this case i need the field `Dev`.

Answer (score 2):

`var sect = configuration.GetSection("Config");` returns null because `Config` section has no key and value, instead it has a `SubSection` which is `Production`. `Key` and `Value` reside in the lowest level of this hierarchy.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2) is the details from Microsoft of reading `appsettings.json` file in ASP.NET Core.

According to the above documentation you need to do as follows to read the values from `appsettings.json` file:

```
var hostName = configuration.GetSection("Config:Production:RedisAddress:Hostname").Value; // will return the value "redis0" for key `HostName`
var port = configuration.GetSection("Config:Production:RedisAddress:Port").Value; // will return the value 6379 for key `Port`
var aa = configuration.GetSection("tt:aa").Value; // will return 3
```

Following the above methodology you can read any value from the `appsettings.json` file:

Answer (score 0):

This if how I made it work

```
"Localization": {
  "DefaultCulture": "en-US",
  "SupportedCultures": [
    "en-US",
    "no-NB",
    "uk-UA",
    "ru-RU"
  ],
  "SupportedUICultures": [
    "en-US",
    "no-NB",
    "uk-UA",
    "ru-RU"
  ]
}
```

```
var localizationSection = this.configuration.GetRequiredSection("Localization");
options.AddSupportedCultures(localizationSection.GetRequiredSection("SupportedCultures").Get<string[]>());
options.AddSupportedUICultures(localizationSection.GetRequiredSection("SupportedUICultures").Get<string[]>());
options.SetDefaultCulture(localizationSection.GetRequiredSection("DefaultCulture").Get<string>());
```