# Configuration.GetSection is returning null in .net core (3.1)

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, configuration

I am trying to get information appSettings.json file using "Configuation.GetSection". but somehow i am not able to get this.

here is the code

appSettings.Development.json:

```
{
    "test": {
    "a": "sdfs"
}
```

startup.cs

```
var test = Configuration.GetSection("test");
```

is there anything I need to run get the information from appsettings.json file.

[image]

[image]

please help. thanks in advance

Comment: thats  in not part of .net core 3.1 . I can see files are loading under root property

Comment: yes I am certain about that.

Comment: updated screenshot where I can see json files and data inside those file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Configuration.GetSection always returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46017593/configuration-getsection-always-returns-null)

Answer (score 4):

I think I found the  answer to above problem.  I am not sure I am right or not.

I wanted to take settings from "apSettings.json" file and create an object of it and then use it with DI into my controller.

for that I used this way now.

inside ConfigureServices method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        AppSettings _settings = new AppSettings();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Bind(_settings);// bind is necessary
        services.AddSingleton(_settings);
    }
```

(Note: AppSettings is custom class which will have properties mentioned in appSettings.json)

option 2:
this is second option to get information from "appsettings.json".

```
services.AddSingleton<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Get<AppSettings>();
```

Answer (score 3):

[Configuration.GetSection()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#getsection) Method returns a configuration subsection with the specified subsection key, it return the specified ConfigurationSection object. You could use the below ways to get the data :

1.Get the section from the configuration object. Inside this, we are getting another section that contains the value.

```
var test = Configuration.GetSection("Test").GetSection("a").Value;
```

2.Directly get the string type value from configuration object. We are separating our nested sections by “:”.

```
string dbConn2 = Configuration.GetValue<string>("Test:a");
```

Reference:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/reading-values-from-appsettings-json-in-asp-net-core/

Answer (score 1):

I was also faced with a similiar issue, where IConfiguration was "null", in that the key/value pairs I had placed in the appsettings.json file were not being read. I did a bit of experimentation, and I had found this approach to work (this is in .net core 3.1):

In the application's Program.cs file, you add your Configuration file configuration:

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
                 .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                 
                 .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                 {
                     webBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration(x =>
                     {
                         x.SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
                         x.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
                         x.AddEnvironmentVariables();
                         x.Build();
                     });

                     webBuilder.UseKestrel(config =>
                     {
                         
                     })
                     .UseIIS()
                     .UseStartup<Startup>();
                 }).Build();
            host.Run();
```

Comment: Brilliant. This is what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you configure it right

appsettings.json

```
{
  ...
  "Test": {
    "Key": "Value" 
  }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }      
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }


    ...

    string v = Configuration["Test:Key:Value"];

    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Mateech, I  have configured it right. currently If I give only "Test" as key it is not coming . but If I give "Test:a". it gives me value. strange thing.

Comment: Hi @DeepakSingh, you can try to get it that way: `..GetSection("test").GetValue<string>("a")`

Comment: yeah, I can do that but it will give me one value I want bind the settings into object. and then use it using DI.

Comment: @DeepakSingh maybe this can be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46017593/configuration-getsection-always-returns-null