# Options Values are always empty/null for a Dictionary configuration section

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to bind this appsettings section to my Options but it is not working as expected

here is my config section inside `appsettings.json`:

```
"Tenants": {
    "First": {
        "Name": "Example 1"
    },
    "Second": {
        "Name": "Example 2"
    }
}
```

Here are my Options models:

```
public class Tenant
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class TenantsOptions
{
    public Dictionary<string, Tenant> Tenants { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, Tenant>();
}

public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // ...
        services.Configure<TenantsOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("Tenants"));

        // Other service configurations...
    }
}
```

and when I try to use it somewhere:

```
public class TenantController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly TenantsOptions _tenantsOptions;

    public TenantController(IOptions<TenantsOptions> tenantsOptions)
    {
        _tenantsOptions = tenantsOptions.Value;
    }

    [HttpGet("tenants")]
    public IActionResult GetTenants()
    {
        var tenants = _tenantsOptions.Tenants.Values; // this is always empty/null why?
        return Ok(tenants);
    }
}
```

For example this works and it is giving me the values:

```
var options = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Tenants").Get<Dictionary<string, Tenant>>();
```

Now I've seen many ways to achieve the same thing (using `.GetValue` from config for example) but I want to do it this way only getting the options from the DI, is this possible or I am missing something?

Comment: This is possible duplicate, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61382986/configuration-getsection-is-returning-null-in-net-core-3-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code seems to expect a `Tenants` object inside an another `Tenants` object, which is missing. Here are a couple ways of solving this.

### Option 1

Remove the GetSection method call.

```
services.Configure<TenantsOptions>(Configuration/*.GetSection("Tenants")*/);
```

### Option 2

Change your JSON code to the following

```
"Tenants": {
  "Tenants": {// <--
    "First": {
      "Name": "Example 1"
    },
    "Second": {
      "Name": "Example 2"
    }
  }// <--
},
```