# How can Autofac and an Options pattern be used in a .NET 5 console application?

Tags: c#, autofac

I am trying to use an option pattern with Autofac and every attempt has just resulted in errors.

What I've tried:

1. Using the ConfigurationBuilder to retrieve an IConfiguration/IConfigurationRoot.
2. Register an instance of `TestSectionOptions` using the IConfiguration/IConfigurationRoot that was created before:
   `builder.Register(c => config.GetSection("TestSection").Get<TestSectionOptions>());`
3. Trying to inject it via constructor injection:

```cs
private readonly TestSectionOptions _options;
    
public DemoClass(IOptions<TestSectionOptions> options)
{
    _options = options.Value;
}
```

I'm getting following error:

> DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with
> 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type
> 'DemoApp.DemoClass' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
> Cannot resolve parameter
> 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1[DemoApp.TestSectionOptions] options' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1

Of course I tried other types of registration, but none of them worked.
I also know that I can simply bind the configuration file to a class, which I then register and inject without the IOptions<> part. But that would no longer correspond exactly to the option pattern, would it?
Even if it doesn't make a big difference, I'd still like to know why it doesn't work and how I could get it to work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get IOptions in ConfigureServices method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42932711/how-to-get-ioptions-in-configureservices-method)

Comment: Unfortunately not directly applicable to Autofac, your example is using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection which is (I think) doing something under the hood that I'm missing, but big thanks tho!

I think I'm on the right track!
I could make my class implement `IConfigureOptions<TOptions>` / `IConfigureNamedOptions<TOptions>` but I'm still not 100% sure. I will give it a try and reply if I found a proper way.

Comment: “ But that would no longer correspond exactly to the option pattern, would it?” What is the option pattern? I mean, if you write options = options.Value right in the constructor, what advantage of this pattern do you use?

Comment: E.g. it might throw an exception for invalid settings, or, if you have validation, but it will have no difference, if you dereference it in the constructor. Btw, I really dont see what advantages it brings, except for validation - even worse - it looks like it might support settings value changing, but it onky looks so, but really you would have to use IOptionsSnapshot or IOptionsMonitor. I.e. it is a bit confusing.

Comment: You're totally right @ViktorArsanov and thank you very much for your answer.
But as I mentioned above, I'm not interested in the difference, I just wanna know how to solve it and what's the problem, I'm just really curious!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that this IOptions type should be registerd somewhere.

You can see e.g. [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-5.0). There is an example

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<PositionOptions>(Configuration.GetSection(
                                        PositionOptions.Position));
    services.AddRazorPages();
}
```

So, somewhere inside Configure extension method it registers types for options, among others IOptions<>.

So, in your case you either have to do this explicitly, like

```
builder.Register(c => Options.Create(config.GetSection("TestSection").Get<TestSectionOptions>()))
```

This will register IOptions

or, you can create an empty service collection, then call Configure method on it, and then copy all registrations to autofac builder - there is Populate method from the package "Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection"

https://autofac.org/apidoc/html/B3162450.htm

Comment: Options.Create was what I was searching for, thank you